# Are people still concious after beheading?

Tags: physiology, mortality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does one remain conscious after decapitation?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/does-one-remain-conscious-after-decapitation)

Is it true that after you are beheaded, you are still concious for a few seconds, and you can see everything around?

Comment: would be near impossible to prove or disprove, the only thing that can be shown is continued brain activity by hooking up someone to an ECG and then beheading them. Are you willing to volunteer as a test subject? :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Your question was very similar to another and it has been closed for this reason. More info on what this means here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/faq-my-question-was-closed-what-does-it-mean